# Making server use request pipelines along with accepting Blazor calls

Tags: routes, httpclient, middleware, pipeline, blazor

I am using `browser`-hosted `Blazor` and in my `server` project i want to use additional `middleware`'s.
The problem is:

How can i make my server respond both  `Blazor` calls and use request pipelines for `api` calls?

**Code**

**Server Startup**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {

        app.UseBlazor<Client.Startup>();
        app.Map("/apiRoute", x => {
            Console.WriteLine("got here");
        });
```

**P.S** 
In the following code i can access `Blazor` routes but i can't access the `apiRoute`.
Is there a way to make this work considering i want to create pipelines ?

I have placed the `pipeline` both before and after the `app.UseBlazor` to no avail.It just won't get hit.

**Update**

Apparently i made `middleware`-s work alongside `Blazor` with the following constraints :

1. Using the middleware(s) before using `Blazor` in the request pipeline
2. For custom `routes` , it seems the extension `app.Map(route,x=>...)` does not work with `Blazor` so i had to wrap it inside a `app.Use` extension.

**Code**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();


            app.Use(async (con, next) => {
                app.Map("/myCustomRoute", f => {
                    app.Use(async (c, n) => {
                        await con.Response.Body.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("asa"));
                    });
                });
            });
            app.UseBlazor<Client.Startup>();
        }
```

With the above code i can access `Blazor` pages as well as  sending from `Postman` a request on the specified route ( in our case `myCustomRoute`) that gets hit,although i still get no response back to `Postman`.
What i still do not understand is why i can't branch my pipeline (`app.Map`) and use the `Blazor` extension next since they are different concerns.

**Example** 
 
Why does this not work:

```
    app.Map("myroute1",...);
    app.Map("myroute2",...);
    app.UseBlazor(...);
```

and this works:

```
  app.Use(async(x,con)=>{
                  app.Map(route1,...);
                  app.Map(route2....);
               });
  app.UseBlazor(....)
```

Comment: What this code is supposed to do, and did you run your app first without it : app.Map("/route", (x =>
            {
                ---
             }

Comment: I ran the code without using any middleware and i get the same error.The method in the client just does a `POST`(with an object)  on the server using `HttpClient` on the specified route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently i made `middleware`-s work alongside `Blazor` with the following constraints :

1. Using the middleware(s) before using `Blazor` in the request pipeline
2. For custom `routes` , it seems the extension `app.Map(route,x=>...)` does not work with `Blazor` so i had to wrap it inside a `app.Use` extension.

**Code**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();


            app.Use(async (con, next) => {
                app.Map("/myCustomRoute", f => {
                    app.Use(async (c, n) => {
                        await con.Response.Body.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("asa"));
                    });
                });
            });
            app.UseBlazor<Client.Startup>();
        }
```

The above code works if i access `Blazor` pages as well as  sending from `Postman` a request on the specified route ( in our case `myCustomRoute`).
What i still do not understand is why i can't branch my pipeline (`app.Map`) and use the `Blazor` extension next since they are different concerns.

**Example** 
 
Why does this not work:

```
app.Map("myroute1",...);
app.Map("myroute2",...);
app.UseBlazor(...);
```

and this works:

```
 app.Use(async(x,con)=>{
              app.Map(route1,...);
              app.Map(route2....);
           });
 app.UseBlazor(....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Remove `app.Map("/route", (x => { --- }`

And change your code to something like this:

```
var response = await this.client.PostAsync("/route",
                                   content);
```

Comment: So you are saying that i can not use middlewares/pipelines (`app.Map`)` when using `Blazor` ?